# How can I join Two Tables with and intermediate Table and gather data?

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-query-builder

I am working on a project and I needed to retrieve data from an Table A to Table C with a Table B as an intermediate using the `HasManyThrough` from Laravel Doc  [Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

I have three Tables  `Categorie` `Sous`*`Categorie` and `Produit`, This is the realtionship:

`Categorie` --> Hasmany `Sous_Categorie` -->Hasmany `Produits`.*

```
And this is my tables 
Categorie:
   - id
   - name
Sous_categorie:
   - id
   - categorie_id
   - name
Produits:
   - id
   - sous_categorie_id
   - name
```

And this are  my Models

`Categorie.php`

```
class Categorie extends Model
{
public function souscategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Sous_categorie::class, 'sous_categorie');
    }

    public function produits()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Produit::class, Sous_categorie::class);
    }
}
```

`Sous_Categorie.php`

```
class Sous_categorie extends Model
{ 
public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Categorie::class,'categorie_id','id');
    }

    public function produits(){
        return $this->hasMany(Produit::class,'produit');
    }
}
```

`Produit.php`

```
class Produit extends Model
{
public function souscategories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Sous_categorie::class, 'sous_categorie_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I also added the:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'filenames',
        'title',
        'nom',
        'sous_categorie_id',
        'categorie_id',
        'id',
        'id'

    ];
```

What Am trying to do is to get all the product from a specified Category based on and ID for example:

I have `categorie` Called `PC PARTS` and a `Sous_categorie` belongs to `PC PARTS` has many `Produits` that I want to retrive.

I hope My Problem is Clear, Thanks in Advance.

I tried to get all `produits` with a join between `souscategories.categories` relationship with `categorie_id` like this

```
$s_produits = Produit::with('souscategories.categories')->where('categorie_id','like','%'.$id.'%')->get();
```

I get This Error:
**`` SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categorie_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `produits` where `categorie_id` like %1%) ``**

If I try this line of code:

```
$s_produits = Produit::with('souscategories.categories')->get();
```

it retrieve all product available

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrQ31.png)
which I don't want I want all products from a certain category

Answer (score 0):

I see that you wnat to filter the `Produit` model based on `categorie_id` in `souscategories` table ? You can add a constraints inside `with()` :

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

Produit::with(['souscategories' => function (Builder $query) use ($id) {
    $query->where("categorie_id","LIKE", %{$id}%);
}])->get();
```

[Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) here the reference.

Comment: It didn't work can you be more specific plz

Comment: The is the error App\Http\Controllers\SousCategorieController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(): Argument #1 ($query) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Database\Eloquent\Builder,

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out how to join table A with table B with a table C and an intermediate table.
so I have table `categories` hasMany `sous_categories` hasMany `produits` i was trying to retrieve all products based on a categories name with this code:

```
public function show(Sous_categorie $sous_categorie, $id)
{
    //
    $s_produits = DB::table('produits')
    ->select('produits.*', 'sous_categories.categorie_id as laravel_through_key')
    ->join('sous_categories','sous_categories.id','=','produits.sous_categorie_id')
    ->whereIn('sous_categories.categorie_id',[$id])
    ->get();
}
```

it's works fine with a 156ms query duration if i can make it any simpler please tell me.